# Git - How to see if a branch has EVER been merged into another branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

If I have a feature branch F and master branch M, then

```
git branch --merged
```

while on master will show me if F has been entirely merged into M, but how can I tell if it has EVER been merged?

I've tried looking through the git-log manual and from what I can tell

```
git log M..F
```

will show me the revs on F that haven't been merged into M. I'd like to see the inverse of that, the revs on F that have been merged into M.

There are a whole bunch of questions which are close to this but don't seem to cover this particular case.2

Answer (score 6):

Use `git log`:

```
git log feature_branch master --oneline --date-order --merges --reverse -1
```

This will show you all merges betwee feature_branch and master. `--reverse` will output the commits in reverse order. And `-1` means to show only `one` commit. Therefore you'll see only the first merged commit.

If this is an empty output than it means nothing is merged. If you want you can remove the `-1` at the end to show all merged commits beginning with the latest.

Comment: Ahhh this is interesting, I didn't think about using --merges. I don't think the above command actually does what you say it does, though. Doesn't `git log master..feature_branch` give you the commits that are in feature_branch but not master? and then adding `--merges` to it will filter those for ANY merges, not explicitly the merges of feature_branch into master?

Answer (score 3):

**1.** lists the branches that are already merged

```
git branch --merged
```

**2.** lists the branches that have not been merged (if its not there that means its merged)

```
git branch --no-merged
```

Comment: Yes, but doesn't this deal only with the case of ENTIRELY merged? If F was merged into M at some stage in its life, I want to be able to see that.